# How to mock http.Head()

Tags: unit-testing, go, mocking

I'm studying the outyet example project from https://github.com/golang/example/tree/master/outyet. The [test file](https://github.com/golang/example/blob/master/outyet/main_test.go) does not cover the case where [`http.Head(url)`](https://github.com/golang/example/blob/master/outyet/main.go#L98) returns an error. I would like to extend the unit tests to cover the if statement where the error is logged (https://github.com/golang/example/blob/master/outyet/main.go#L100). I would like to mock `http.Head()`, but I'm not sure how to do this. How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `http.Head` function simply calls the [`Head` method](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.Head) on the default HTTP client (exposed as `http.DefaultClient`).  By replacing the default client within your test, you can change the behaviour of these standard library functions.

In particular, you will want a client that sets a custom transport (any object implementing the [`http.RoundTripper`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#RoundTripper) interface).  Something like the following:

```
type testTransport struct{}

func (t testTransport) RoundTrip(request *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    # Check expectations on request, and return an appropriate response
}

...

savedClient := http.DefaultClient
http.DefaultClient = &http.Client{
    Transport: testTransport{},
}

# perform tests that call http.Head, http.Get, etc

http.DefaultClient = savedClient
```

You could also use this technique to mock network errors by returning an error from your transport rather than an HTTP response.